# How to extract and port an "SQL Server 2008 database embedded CLR assembly" to a MySQL 5.5 database equivalent?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server-2008, windows-services, sqlclr

### My Goal:

To extract and port a SQL Server CLR assembly embedded in an SQL Server 2008 database to an equivalent supported by a MySQL 5.5 database.

I have a SQL Server 2008 database which i am trying to port to MySQL 5.5. The database is part of an ASP.NET based website which needs to use MySQL instead of SQL Server (please dont ask why?)

This database also makes use of **a custom built, SQL Server (CLR?) assembly** which i can see when i access the following section of the database using SQL Server Management Studio.

```
[Database Name] > Programmability > Assemblies >Namespace.MyCustomSQLServerAssembly
```

I do NOT have access to the source code for that assembly as the previous coder did not provide it as part of the source code package but i believe if i could decompile the assembly if i could extract it.

I have ported all stored procedures and tables successfully however i have no idea how to port this assembly. Maybe i am not using the right keywords, but i could not find any tutorial on "how to port this assembly to MySQL" using Google. I understand that it may not be directly possible.

At this point i have the following questions:

1. How to extract this assembly from the SQL Server Database?
2. Can this assembly (if successfully extracted) could be decompiled to code (SQL or C#)?
3. Is there any equivalent in MySQL Server which i can create which could provide the replacement to this assembly which i want to extract from SQL Server database and subsequently port (assuming if it defines custom data types only)?

Note:

The types from these assemblies seems to be referenced in user defined functions in the same database.

Some of the above question may sound a little bit noob, but i havent written any CLR assembly before that can be loaded and run in SQL Server as part of SQL Server database.

This is the last step in porting the database to mysql. All stored procedures and functions have already been ported but i have no clue how to extract/port this assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extracted the SQL Server library from database using this question at Stackoverflow.com.

[Extracting a .NET Assembly from SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103406/extracting-a-net-assembly-from-sql-server-2005)

and used Red Gate .NET Reflector to decompile the library. Now i think i can create custom functions or stored procedures in MySQL to mimic the same functions defined in the library.