# How can I export an assembly file in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I am currently migrating a SQL Server database where a co-worker once created this dll using C#, but now I am struggling with it, since I have no idea how I can export mentioned dll, have seen that I need to make a c# function, but I don't understand quite well what I have to do

Does someone have been in the same situation? Do you have any idea how can I achieve this? Thanks a lot I'd really appreciate if you can help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting a .NET Assembly from SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103406/extracting-a-net-assembly-from-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score -2):

In sql server management studio, you could right-click the database, choose Tasks->Generate Script. Then search for a line of code that starts with "CREATE ASSEMBLY" - part of that line will be a long string of numbers, which is the dll