# CLR function migration how to extract code from assembly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlclr

I need to migrate instance of SQL Server and found that I don't have a source code for a few CLR functions anywhere, I see functions in assembly and know their logic:

`select * from sys.assembly_modules`

Is it possible to extract source code from it, so I will store it in newly added TFS.

Actually now main task is to have same CLR functions on a new server, so probably just migrating assemblies will do the job? Or this will require do some extra steps?

And on step2 I will probably will try to recreate source code if reverse engineering won't work.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/deploying-clr-database-objects?view=sql-server-ver15#deploying-the-assembly-to-production-servers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting a .NET Assembly from SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103406/extracting-a-net-assembly-from-sql-server-2005)

Comment: Probably, to meet your requirements, you'll need to create another CLR assembly with code to extract the CRL assemblies; recommended lectures is commend above by @DaleK or this article [Exporting CLR Assemblies from SQL Server back to .dll files](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3126/exporting-clr-assemblies-from-sql-server-back-to-dll-files/)

Answer (score 1):

An SQLCLR function is part of an assembly. An assembly can contain multiple functions. It can (in theory) be made up of multiple files, although that is unusual.

You can get the actual DLL files with this

```sql
SELECT
  a.name AssemblyName,
  f.name FileName,
  f.content Dll
FROM sys.assemblies a
JOIN sys.assembly_files f ON f.assembly_id = a.assembly_id
-- if you want to filter to certain SQLCLR functions
/*
WHERE a.assembly_id IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.assembly_modules m
    WHERE m.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'YourFunction')
)
*/
```

You can de-compile the DLLs with your favorite .NET decompiler.

If you want to just transfer them, you can commit them to source control as `CREATE ASSEMBLY FROM`  followed by the binary data

Answer (score 1):

Making Charlieface's second recommendation more explicit, just transfer the assembly. You can do this through SSMS by choosing the assembly in Object Explorer and selecting "Script Assembly as..." from the context menu. Of course, since that just uses SMO on the back end, you can also do this with a little scripting. Here's a quick-and-dirty powershell script (`Get-DbaDatabase` coming from the always delightful dbatools module).

```
$db = Get-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance yourServer -Database yourDB;
foreach ($a in ($db.Assemblies | where IsSystemObject -eq $false)){
    $a.Script();
}
```